# HTML code trying to load PDF file from Site using ssl with self signed certificate

Tags: ssl, https, wireshark, packet

My employer has a web application that loads a pdf file onto the client browser by having a code that does the ff:

embed src="https://somepage.somesite.com/folderpath/somefile.pdf" width="100%" height="100%"

Things to note:

- The site being accessed uses a self signed certificate
- The clients loading the PDF file are located on a different network connected via site to site VPN to my employer's network.
- The client can resolve the hostname "somepage.somesite.com"
- Connectivity tests have proven that clients can reach somepage.somesite.com and port 443 is open to them

Despite all these tests the PDF file still fails to load onto the client's browser and just hangs :

[PDF file hanging upon loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0mST.png)

Now we also did some Wireshark packet captures and we got this we saw that the client was able to initiate a TLS handshake with the site but it only goes thru:

- Client Hello
- Server Hello
- Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done

Followed by 
 - Client > Server ACK
 - Client > Server [FIN,ACK]
 - then Client > Server SYN

This cycle keeps on repeating on the packet trace while the html page hangs in loading the pdf.

Any idea on the cause of this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try a different browser, and two browsers from a different network location.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's not working on IE11 (Or any version) but it works for Chrome